# Is there a synonym for laziness or procrastination

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

...that starts with the letter 'w', 'h', or 'e'?

I'm in desperate need of such a word to fit the essay I'm writing :D

Comment: I don't see *procrastination* and *laziness* as particularly synonymous in the first place. *Procrastination* to me implies (possibly vigorous) distractive activity or speech, involving actual effort intended to hinder the progress of something considered important by others. Active resistance, if you will. *Laziness* simply means unwillingness to do anything at all.

Comment: My bad. I meant a synonym of any of those words. So a synonym of laziness OR a synonym for procrastination.

Answer (score 2):

**[waffling](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=define%3a%20waffling&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#hl=en&q=waffle&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=mj8FTvLPB8mDtgfpvqDGDQ&ved=0CBYQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=2f4d54d3f27653ca&biw=1281&bih=683)**
**[hebetude](http://www.wordnik.com/words/hebetude)**
**[ergophobia](http://www.wordnik.com/words/ergophobia)**

Comment: I like ergophobia. I could claim not to be ponophobic but that means I'd have to finish this....

Answer (score 1):

My thesaurus found *work-shy*:

> (of a person) lazy and disinclined to work

Answer (score 0):

Well, not precisely, but Try:

halfhearted, effete, wasteful